# oracle sql check constraint condition met

Tags: sql, oracle

Beginner question:
Is there a way to write a check constraint that restricts data where a condition is met. For instance, if I want to not allow appointment times between 1100 and 1300 on a specific day.

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_info
 ADD CONSTRAINT ap_time_ck CHECK (ap_time NOT BETWEEN 11 and 13);
```

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_info
 ADD CONSTRAINT ap_time_ck CHECK (ap_time NOT BETWEEN 11 and 13 AND ap_date != '02-APR-2014');
```

But obviously that will restrict all appointment times between 1100 and 1300 and any appointments on April 2nd.

Comment: thats what i thought but my check constraint is violated because i have an appointment set for april 2nd at 1400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible solution:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_info
ADD CONSTRAINT ap_time_ck CHECK (not (ap_time BETWEEN 11 and 13 and ap_date = date '2014-04-02'));
```

I am against using this: `'02-APR-2014'` because it can depend on NLS settings.

Or just change `and` condition to `or` in your attempt. It would also work.

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_info
ADD CONSTRAINT ap_time_ck CHECK (ap_time NOT BETWEEN 11 and 13 OR ap_date != '02-APR-2014');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the first solution you gave.